# Finding a generalized form for taking the n$^{th}$ derivative of a falling factorial

Tags: calculus, derivatives, symmetric-polynomials

I would like to make

$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[(x)_c] = n! \times e_{c-n}(x,x-1,\cdots,x-c+1)
$$

Where $e_{c-n}(x,x-1,x-2,\cdots,x-c+1)$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial function

But lets say that i have

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-c}f(k) \frac{d^k}{dx^k}[(x)_c]
$$

If $k>c$ then the derivative is zero, But if i replace $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}[(x)_c]$with $k!\times e_{c-k}(x,x-1,\cdots,x-c+1)$ then i get

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-c}k!f(k) e_{c-k}(x,x-1,\cdots,x-c+1)
$$
If $k>c$ then would $e_{c-k}(x,x-1,\cdots,x-c+1)=0$? If not how can i fix this problem?

Comment: $(x)_c$ is a polynomial of order *c* in *x*, whose coefficients are [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: @Lucian This is true, but i don't know what this has to do with my question.

Comment: It's relevant to your question because if you write $(x)_c$ as a polynomial in the conventional way, then taking derivatives is easy. - Also, how is $e_j$ defined?

Comment: @GregMartin It is the elementary symmetric polynomial, also it is good to note that due to the chain rule
$$
(x)_4 = x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}[(x)_4] = x(x-1)(x-2)+x(x-1)(x-3)+x(x-2)(x-3)+(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = e_3(x,x-1,x-2,x-3)
$$

Comment: Ok, I find it easier to understand now. So your question is: is it reasonable to define $e_{-j}(\cdots)=0$? I think that's totally reasonable.

Comment: @GregMartin yes